# import script and run it with APScheduler with Python

Tags: python, apscheduler

I'm setting up a scheduler with APScheduler:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

sched = BlockingScheduler()
@sched.scheduled_job('interval', seconds=3)

def scheduled_job():
    print("test")
    import runccvtest
sched.start()
```

It 's running well with the print statement but the 3 seconds interval doesn' with the runccvtest which is basically a print statement (it's a test, the real script will be more complicated).

```
print("Hellow world")
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: Try wrapping the import in a try...except block and see if there's an exception coming from the import. Alternatively, add a listeners to the scheduler to be notified of exceptions  from the job run.

Comment: That was it, thanks !